# How do I fit a simple filter with R?

Tags: r, time-series

I have two timeseries, `y[t]` and `x[t]`. A domain expert tells me that `y[t]` should be a linear combination of past values of `x[t]` up to a certain horizon, i.e.

```
y[t] = a[0]*x[t] + a[1]*x[t-1] + ... + a[n]*x[t-n]
```

How do I estimate the `a[i]` coefficients in R? Indeed, what is the proper name for this kind of model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [distributed lag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lag) model. The model from of your example can be estimated with simple linear regression. You can use *dynlm* package for easier lag handling:

```
> library(dynlm)
> n<-4 ##Number of lag used in a model
> data("USDistLag", package = "lmtest")
> dynlm(consumption~L(gnp,0:4))

Time series regression with "ts" data:
Start = 1967, End = 1982

Call:
dynlm(formula = consumption ~ L(gnp, 0:4), data = USDistLag)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)  L(gnp, 0:4)Series 1  L(gnp, 0:4)Series 2  L(gnp, 0:4)Series 3  
          -30.54113              0.46253              0.09632             -0.06309  
L(gnp, 0:4)Series 4  L(gnp, 0:4)Series 5  
            0.13511              0.03176
```